# Does the @@iterate_diff view from plone.app.iterate work with plone.app.stagingbehavior?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a custom type made using [dexterity](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/) and [plone.app.stagingbehavior](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.stagingbehavior) installed. I can check in and check out my custom type, but trying to view the diff results in a stack trace because [plone.app.iterate.browser.diff.DiffView](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.iterate/blob/master/plone/app/iterate/browser/diff.py) doesn't seem to know how to get the baseline and working copy versions for objects made using dexterity/p.a.stagingbehavior.

I did try overriding DiffView and changing it to use get_baseline and get_working_copy from from [plone.app.stagingbehavior.utils](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.stagingbehavior/blob/master/plone/app/stagingbehavior/utils.py), but the diff view still doesn't work (with a different exception, ten thousand levels deep in Products.Archetypes, so I assume it's not likely to work). Perhaps collective.dexteritydiff would help at this point.

It's a bit confusing because p.a.stagingbehavior includes a link to @@iterate_diff in its version of the [plone.app.iterate.checkout_info](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.stagingbehavior/blob/master/plone/app/stagingbehavior/browser/info_baseline.pt) portlet, which makes me think it's intended to work and maybe my setup is broken or I've done something wrong.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this, I never did find a solution, and ended up hiding the diff button for dexterity content.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed in Products.CMFDiffTool 2.0.2, which was released with Plone 4.2.5: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.CMFDiffTool

Comment: This is still a problem for me with Document/Page from plone.app.contenttypes 1.0,  Plone 4.3.2 & CMFDiffTool 2.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to `plone.app.iterate.browser.diff.DiffView` not being compatible with Dexterity yet. The diff-view calls `context.getReferences` which raises an AttributeError on dexterity objects. Since this happens in a `__init__` method the traceback is swallowed. It should use `__call__` and code to get the references like `plone.app.stagingbehavior.utils` does.